# How to send request to another server and response the result in pyramid view?

Tags: python, image, web, pyramid

I want to response some .png image in my pyramid view. I know the url for that image.
I tried urllib, urllib2, requests, but they response object that pyramid view does not understand. 
My code like this:

```
def image_handler(request):
    url = "http://someurl.com/image.png"
    import urllib2
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return response
```

I tried `response.read()` too.

Any suggestions?
I want that user see image in his web browser

Comment: i cannot use HTTPFound or other redirecting tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no `renderer` specified in your Pyramid view configuration, your view function is supposed to return a Pyramid Response object, you can't just return random stuff :) Apart from the actual response body, the Response object also encapsulates headers, HTTP response code and other stuff needed to build a correct HTTP response.

[urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) returns a "file-like object". [pyramid.response](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html) has a property called `body_file` which can be assigned a file-like object which contents will be sent to the client.

So, I would start with something like this:

```
import urllib2

def image_handler(request):
    url = "http://someurl.com/image.png"
    image_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    request.response.body_file = image_file
    request.response.content_type = 'image/png'  
    return request.response
```

or, less, efficient, with `.read()`

```
def image_handler2(request):
    url = "http://someurl.com/image.png"
    image_blob = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    request.response.body = image_blob
    request.response.content_type = 'image/png'  
    return request.response
```

(both examples untested, treat as pseudocode)

Comment: Thank you, yes i did it yesterday, but anyway thanks for two advice.
 with `.read()` like this
`response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
return Response(body = response, content_type="image/png")`